# How can I change some properties of a textbox when created with gr.Interface?

Tags: python, gradio

I'm following the basic Gradio interface from the [Gradio documentation](https://www.gradio.app/docs/interface):

```
import gradio as gr

def greet(name):
    return "Hello " + name + "!"

#demo = gr.Interface(fn=greet, inputs="text", outputs="text")

demo.launch()
```

The interface is:

[image]

How can I change some properties of the output textbox? E.g., I'd like to set [`autoscroll`](https://www.gradio.app/docs/textbox) to False.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered [gradio](/questions/tagged/gradio) but seems like the `outputs` parameter accepts any `IOComponent` (*like a* [`Textbox`](https://www.gradio.app/docs/textbox)) as an argument :

```
import gradio as gr

def greet(name):
    return "Hello " + name + "!"
        
demo = gr.Interface(
    fn=greet,
    inputs="text",
    outputs=gr.Textbox(max_lines=3, autoscroll=False)
)

demo.launch()
```

*NB: In the demo below, I'm shadowing your `greet` function to make a default long input text.*

[image]